# Crontab failing to restart systemctl process

Tags: cron, systemctl, ubuntu-22.04

Hi im trying to setup a cron job to restart a game server daily but its failing to work

i have used `crontab -e` to install a job

`* 3 * * * systemctl --user restart <servicename>`
this failed to restart my process at 3 am as expected.

i also tried moving the command to a bash file and running the bash file through cron (as i have seen alot of people use .sh files to run commands)

additionally i have tried installing to job as root with zero success

this had similar results

my syslog did show a command execute as expected yesterday though the service didnt restart, since then cron isnt showing any new attempts.

i found some info on troubleshooting and following the guidance shows that my cron is working, i managed write the date/time to a file every minute and the service is clearly running and this showed in the logs.

is there a problem with cron running systemctl commands or is there further steps i can use to see why its failing?

Edit:
i tried running my command as root also and nothing happened

```
Jan 31 09:00:01 ns509515 CRON[108307]: (root) CMD (<user> systemctl --user restart EcoServer)
Jan 31 09:01:01 ns509515 CRON[108330]: (root) CMD (<user> systemctl --user restart EcoServer)
Jan 31 09:02:01 ns509515 CRON[108356]: (root) CMD (<user> systemctl --user restart EcoServer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `> /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` after your command and you see error log in `/tmp/cronjob.log`

Answer (score 0):

In the End this was achieved using a systemd timer service.

```
// %h/.config/systemd/user/EcoRestart.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart Eco Server daily

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --user restart EcoServer.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
// %h/.config/systemd/user/EcoRestart.timer
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 08:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

probably not the best or most efficient way, but it serves it's purpose.